# How to sort a repository item?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting

How do I sort my repository, where the item is a `DateTime` collection? I have tried to sort the repository with the following code, but it doesn't works:

```
if (e.Column.FieldName == "date" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
{
    e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox5;
    repositoryItemComboBox5.EditFormat.FormatType = FormatType.DateTime;
    repositoryItemComboBox5.EditFormat.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy";
    repositoryItemComboBox5.Sorted = true;
}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I think it is only sorting the date. I am using DevExpress.

Comment: First do `.Sorted = true` then add the elements.

Comment: can you mention where you bind the list of dateTimes to the combo box? be cause sorting should be applied to the list of data rather than to ComboBox .

Comment: @Prajwal iam adding the elements first then sort

Comment: Please refer this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AminNadimi well, i add it in function `void()` . well for other type such as `string` and `number` works fine with the top code (got sorted). just the datetime that wont sort for some reason if you look at the picture the sorted was only the date

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that a Combobox always represent it's entries by KeyValue, DisplayValue combination. If you add a List of DateTimes each DateTime you show will converted to string to fit the DisplayValue Property. What you see in your picture is a List of strings (just in View, your underlying source is not effected for sure). This way it's sorted like that. 07 starts with 0 which is smallest string, followed by 13 Mar which starts with 1 and so on.

It should be easier for you to sort your DataSource instead of enable the sorting of your Combobox. If you have a `List<DateTime>` for example you can use the following:

```
 List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
 dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 12, 10));
 dates.Add(new DateTime(2016, 12, 10));
 dates.Add(new DateTime(2016, 8, 5));

 dates.Sort();
 repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.AddRange(dates);
```

This will work fine because `DateTime` implements the Interface `ICompareable`.